# What purpose does this antenna-like accessory serve in soldering?

Tags: soldering

I got a new soldering station. I received the following along with the station. I am not sure what is the purpose of it. Please tell me.

[image: Accessory I received along with soldering station]

Update:

Soldering station details:

Aoyue 888A

[image: Product case pic 1]

[image: Product case pic 2]

Comment: Which soldering station is it? The accessory might be named in the included inventory list.

Comment: Brand, model, link to user manual?

Comment: @EugeneSh., I  updated my question with details.

Comment: @Transistor, It is Aoyue 888A

Comment: You have already got the answer, but from the same station sold on amazon, it is listing "1 x IC Popper" among the stuff in the package.

Comment: It doesn't really look like an antenna (or like a very bad one)! More like a fork, or a wishbone.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It's a chip lifter or pick-up wire.
You can shove it underneath a row of pins from a big QFP to lift it up when heating it.
Since tweezers can't usually open that far.

Example video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wd8MY9_bDTY

[image: Still frame from video]

Comment: Interesting, have never seen one of those before. I hope you don't mind that I added a pic from the linked video.

Comment: They call it "IC Popper"

Comment: Never seen one before! Much better than flicking it up with a screwdriver! The things one learns lurking in StackExchange.

Comment: Neat! Never seen one ether. Could be quite clever, or quite dangerous. As shown on the illustration it could leverage over the PCB edge - that seems like a recipe for lifting pads.  Heat + force = lifted pads. If I were to use one of these I would be very careful.

Comment: my money was on "cheap stand attachment for the iron" but i like this a lot more. @Arcatus agreed, this will give very uneven heating across the IC.